# addmin a array inside of another array under a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I have a query and have results from the query so now im doing a foreach loop through the results and based on a value from the result im running another query and getting more data in a seperate array.

```
   $results = some sql query;
   foreach($results as $res) {
       $sub_results = another sql query


       foreach($sub_results as $sub_res) {
            array_push($some_array, array(
                'key1'=>$sub_res['value1'],
                'key2'=>$sub_res['value2'],

             ));
        }

        array_push($final_array, array(
               'somekey'=>$res['value'],
               'somekey2'=>$res['value2'],
               'newkey'=>$some_array,
        ));

    }
```

when i add the $some_array as part of the final_array i am expecting to see only the results that are coresponding to that specific array. so it should look like

```
      [0]=>array(
          'somekey'=>'1',
          'somekey2'=>'2',
          'newkey'=>array(
              have the $some array that corresponds to this specific one and so on
          )
      )
```

but instead im getting the same results under the newkey array inside of the $final_array

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do here.  My guess however is that you could probably resolve all of this with a single database query, as it looks like currently you are using loops to do what you should be doing with a table join.

Comment: How would i create a query that would create the array inside of the array? Thats the reason why i mainly did it this way

Comment: It won't give you an array inside of an array, but it would give you all your records with a single database query.  Splitting a result set into nested arrays is pretty easy if you provide the proper sorting/grouping in your query.  Hard to give exact instruction as you have been vague with regards to what the actual table structure is and how you ultimately want the final array to look (like with real world key information rather than some generic `somekey` type of nomenclature.

Comment: OK so its basically a table with menu items and each item is either a parent or child. there is then another table with access levels for a user. So i need to basically check all the parent items the user has access to grab the parent and then take the parent id and get the children items for that parent and make sure that user has access to all the items

Comment: I actually got it figured out. The problem was the new variable sub_results i was declaring outside of the first foreach loop and when i placed it inside the first foreach loop it works fine thanks for the help